# Is cheese wax compostable?

Tags: composting, food-waste

Is cheese wax compostable? I have some Babybel cheese wax and I was wondering what to do with it.

Comment: it may not be advisable to try and biodegrade the wax but you can re-use it for various purposes.

Comment: @Trav but what? I wonder what it would smell like as a candle!

Answer (score 4):

[Babybel wax](https://www.minibabybel.ca/en-ca/faq-0) is made of a blend of paraffin and microcrystalline waxes and colouring.

[This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/004565359290291X) seems to say that paraffin waxes are biodegradable, but I only have access to the abstract:

> The wax components, n-and iso-alkanes with up to 50 carbon units were found to be rapidly and completely degraded within 28 days leaving only minute wax residues at the end of the test. The degradation of wax components was hardly influenced by the blended polymers.

[This statement](https://www.dominatorwax.com/sites/default/files/dominator/THE-ENVIRONMENTAL-IMPACT-OF-WAXING.pdf) claims microcrystalline waxes, as used in ski wax, are biodegradable, but it is produced by the wax makers and does not provide references.

Answer (score 3):

Cheese wax is made mostly of paraffin, which is petroleum-based, so it is not compostable.

Answer (score 0):

Paraffin wax is petroleum based therefore is not biodegradable.... if you have left over waxes, best solution is simply trash it. Trying to recycle it, not a hugely economical endeavor.

If you have it in LARGE quantities like large scale cheese, deli, operation...

Best thing to do, if you have alot...melt it all down and make a new candle